# New line in Silverlight's label

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I want to know if length of string is bigger then width of `label` then how to adjust string in new line? String apply to label is dynamic.

I have tried using `Viewbox` but that option not worked. anyone got ideas?

Comment: Personally, I ditch all Labels unless there's some specific purpose for it since they inherit from contentcontrol while TextBlock is straight from FrameworkElement so you get to shave a little useless fat by just using TextBlock and also have direct access to TextWrapping for such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `TextWrapping="Wrap"` to TextBlock

oks, something like this may work then?

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName="desiredElement">
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding YourString}"/>
</Label>
```

I don't find Label very useful though, and if this doesn't work out it would be far easier to replace Label with TextBlock with appropriate binding, than mimicing this missing behaviour on it I believe.

Comment: The [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have a `TextWrapping` property.

Comment: well, use TextBlock instead then. Any particular reason to use Label?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub I am printing ID Card that's for i am using label.

Comment: @Prashant16 elaborate please more?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub I have created ID card design using silverlight and in Label i have to display address of employee.

Comment: Label is content control and it makes sense only if you are using its Target property. If you are using target property , place TextBlock inside it. If you are not using Target property, replace it with TextBlock

Comment: Can i set height of TextBlock dynamically?

Comment: Thanks TextBlock is helpful for me

Comment: Yes , you can set its height dynamically through some tricks with bindings and behaviours. You can google this if you decide to go this way.

Answer (score 0):

set the value wrap to TextWrapping.
Here is an example code for doing it for a text block:

```
<TextBlock 
Name="textBlock"

Background="AntiqueWhite" 
Foreground="Navy" 

FontFamily="Century Gothic"
FontSize="12"
FontStretch="UltraExpanded"
FontStyle="Italic"
FontWeight="UltraBold"

LineHeight="Auto"
Padding="5,10,5,10"
TextAlignment="Center"
TextWrapping="Wrap"

Typography.NumeralStyle="OldStyle"
Typography.SlashedZero="True"
>
<Run Background="LightGreen">Text run 1.</Run>
<LineBreak/><Run Background="LightBlue">Text run 2.</Run>
<LineBreak/><Run Background="LightYellow">Text run 3.</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out on `WPF` application so this should work with `silverlight` also

XAML

```
<Label Content="{Binding labelname}">
```

Property

```
  private string _labelname;
   public string labelname
   {
       get
       {
           return _labelname;
       }
       set
       {
           _labelname = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("labelname");
       }
   }
```

Assign the value to property binded like this

```
labelname = "stack" + Environment.NewLine + "overflow";
```

Comment: I have already mention in my question that string is dynamic.